# Find the Value of $a+b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $a + |a| + b= 7  $ and $a + |b| -b =6  $

The above equation  can be solved  by checking different value of $a$ and $b$. But how to do this  by solving the above two equations?

Comment: "The above inequality... " which inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $4$ cases:

1. $a>0,b>0$

$$2a+b=7$$
$$a=6$$

2. $a>0,b<0$

$$2a+b=7$$
$$a-2b=6$$

3. $a<0,b>0$

$$b=7$$
$$a=6$$

4. $a<0,b<0$

$$b=7$$
$$a-2b=6$$

Hence the solutions for $(a,b)$ are $(6,-5),(4,-1),(7,6),(20,7)$ for respective cases.

Considering the respective domains, the only solution is $(4,-1)$.

Comment: Which domain you are talking about?

Comment: @AnuragJain The domain of each solution. Like when $a<0,b>0$ the solution is $a=6,b=7$ but the domain of the solution is taken to be in this case $a<0,b>0$ which is not satisfied. Hence this is not a solution.

Comment: oh yeah, I didn't notice that.

Comment: You should be a bit more careful in your solution writing, your $4$ cases leave out $a$ or $b$ being $0$.

Comment: @Element118 Good point made indeed. But thats a trivial case in this problem, isn't it?

Comment: @Aniket Well, I can say you left out infinitely many cases.

Comment: @Element118 As for example?

Comment: $(x, y)=(0,1),(0,2),(0,3)...$

Comment: @Element118 What are $x,y$ ???

Comment: Oops, I meant $(a, b)$.

Comment: @Element118 And those infinite values do not fall in the $4$ domains I have mentioned but satisfy the equations... is that what you mean? Then I must say think twice before you type the next comment.

Answer (score 3):

Take the first equation, $a +|a|+b=7$.  If $a \lt 0$, this becomes $b=7$, which you can plug into the second equation.  If $a \ge 0$, this becomes $2a+b=7, b=7-2a$, which you can plug into the second.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: 
  a
  >
  0
  ,
  b
  >
  0
:
2a+b=7 and a+b-b=6 i.e. a=6, b=-5 , but this is not the case as we have taken b to be positive but value of b is coming out to be -5.

Case 2: 
  a
  <
  0
  ,
  b
  <
  0
:
a-a+b=7 and a-2b=6 i.e.b=7,a=20, this is also rejected for the similar resason as mentioned in case1.

Case 3: 
  a
  >
  0
  ,
  b
  <
  0
:
2a+b=7, a-2b=6 i.e. b=-1,a=4

Case 4 : 
  a
  <
  0
  ,
  b
  <
  0
:
a-a+b=7 ,a+b-b=6 i.e. b=7, a=6 ,similarly this is not possible.

so our final answer is a=4 and b=-1.

Comment: Please format your equations with mathjax.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: I see many of your previous answers with mathjax. Anyway take a look at this ... http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference .... it will help you forever if you make this a favourite.

Comment: In previous answer I had copied that mathjax syntax from the question only.